# Why is ColdFusion 2016 converting my sender info to lowercase?

Tags: lowercase, coldfusion-2016

We recently upgraded from CF 9.02 to CF 2016 Update 15, and we noticed that the sender details of mails we send are in lowercase.
This is a snipet of the code: `<cfmail from="info@sample.com (Info Sample) ... >"`
The mail is received where the sender name is "info sample", so, converted to lower case.
Has anybody an idea why?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found some kind of workaround. If I change the code from:

```
<cfmail from="info@sample.com (Info Sample) ... >"
```

To:

```
<cfmail from="Info Sample <info@sample.com> ... >"
```

The case is maintained. Has anybody an idea why they changed that? Or is it just a plain bug in CF2016?